# Update Intelliji Idea Java Console Printed Text (No Refresh)

Tags: java

Is it possible to update the Java consoles already printed text without creating a new altered line?

Comment: why don't append your data to a file rather?

Answer (score 0):

> If you re-runan application, the new output overwrites the contents of
> the tab. To preserve the output of an application, even if you re-run
> it, pin the output tab.

please visit jetbrains official [site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-tool-window.html) for more details.

In order to pin tab right click on the tab in run-tool-window and select pin option. Similarly to unpin right click on the tab and select unpin option.

[image: pin tab]